CiviCRm Dashboard
I setup a user dashboard. Everything works great.
But it shows only 12 activity or contributions. No matter how many is there. Am i missing something? Any help please?
Thanks
More friendly dashboard access denied message perhaps?

What did you do to set up the user dashboard? Did you install the new user_dashboard extension? Or are you using something else?

This is what i did.
I created a page call "dashboard"
In that page a inserted a shortdcode "[civicrm component="user-dashboard" hijack="1"]"
That's all.
I can not find a extension "user_dashboard".

Update.
I installed user_dashboard extension.
It does show all contribution.
But it does not show option to download Invoice.
But how do i show more then 12 contributions/activity?
Thank you
